# How to query nullable boolean records in LLBL?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I got into a tricky issue. 
I am trying to query some records, and the data type is nullable Boolean.
Now, I want to query these records based on their values: true, false, null. 
I know how to do true and false, but have no idea how to filter records are null. Can someone help me?

Here is code, the System.DBNull.Value doesn't work.

```
filter.AddWithOr(VwFields.Discontinued == false);
filter.AddWithOr(VwFields.Discontinued == true);
filter.AddWithOr(VwFields.Discontinued == System.DBNull.Value); //wrong
```

Comment: `filter.AddWithOr(VwFields.Discontinued == NULL);`

Comment: @tinka Thanks! But this one is not correct. I tried it earlier. :(

Answer (score 1):

Add extra parenthesis to evaluate the equality condition:

```
filter.AddWithOr((VwFields.Discontinued == System.DBNull.Value));
```

Or use FieldCompareNullPredicate:

```
filter.AddWithOr(new FieldCompareNullPredicate(VwFields.Discontinued));
```